# Obtaining sequential matches between two columns of a data frame returning a list

Tags: r

I have a data frame of two variables (Var1 and Var2). The two elements of each row of the data frame are already matched based on characteristic differences between the two values which were previously established. I.e. 397.1074 is matched to 510.2119 and 436.4694 is also matched to 510.2119.

```
matches <- data.frame(
  Var1 = c(397.1074, 436.4694, 510.2119, 581.2889, 761.0372, 851.5489, 860.3277, 861.0612, 851.5489, 860.3277, 861.0612, 860.3277, 861.0612, 861.0612,
871.4374, 861.0612, 871.4374),
  Var2=c(510.2119, 510.2119, 581.2889, 728.2789, 860.3277, 924.9473, 924.9473, 924.9473, 925.7278, 925.7278, 925.7278, 934.1579, 934.1579, 935.0957,
935.0957, 943.1851, 943.1851)
 ) 
matches
#        Var1     Var2
# 1  397.1074 510.2119
# 2  436.4694 510.2119
# 3  510.2119 581.2889
# 4  581.2889 728.2789
# 5  761.0372 860.3277
# 6  851.5489 924.9473
# 7  860.3277 924.9473
# 8  861.0612 924.9473
# 9  851.5489 925.7278
# 10 860.3277 925.7278
# 11 861.0612 925.7278
# 12 860.3277 934.1579
# 13 861.0612 934.1579
# 14 861.0612 935.0957
# 15 871.4374 935.0957
# 16 861.0612 943.1851
# 17 871.4374 943.1851
```

However, what I am trying to do and am unaware of a function or package suitable for the task is to identify the unbroken chains of matches of the variables from one column to another.

i.e. 397.1074 is matched to 510.2119 in the first row. 510.2119 is matched to 581.2889 in the 3rd row. 581.2889 is matched to 728.2789 in the 4th row. This continues until the value from column 2 can no longer be matched to the values in column 1.

Therefore the first chain of matches would in this case be a vector of length 4 preferably returned as an element within a list :

```
[[1]]
[1] 397.1074 510.2119 581.2889 728.2789
```

The second list element in the result  would therefore be:

```
[[2]]
[1] 436.4694 510.2119 581.2889 728.2789

[[3]] .... Etc.
```

The list result would contain all of the matched elements from columns 1 and 2. Even those of a length of only  two.

Comment: What should be the length of the output? 17 or less? Maybe if you showed the third element of the output it would make things clear.

Comment: List element 3 would be [[3]] 510.2119 581.2889 728.2789

Comment: Sorry I didn't add the rest list element [[4]] 581.2889 728.2789 [[5]] 761.0372 860.3277 924.9473 [[6]] 851.5489 924.9473 and so on

Comment: The length of the list would be the number of rows of the dataframe in this case 17 and the length of each list element would be dependent on if the value in column 2 for that row is further matched in column 1 in another row. Continuing until a match is not made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach, that is probably not that efficient, could be:

```
ff = function(var2)  # a function to, recursively, match each match
{ 
   res = c(var2, matches$Var2[match(tail(var2, 1), matches$Var1)])
   if(!is.na(tail(res, 1))) res = Recall(res)
   return(c(na.omit(res)))
}

lapply(seq_len(nrow(matches)), 
       function(i) c(matches$Var1[i], ff(matches$Var2[i])))
#[[1]]
#[1] 397.1074 510.2119 581.2889 728.2789
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 436.4694 510.2119 581.2889 728.2789
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 510.2119 581.2889 728.2789
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 581.2889 728.2789
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 761.0372 860.3277 924.9473
#
#[[6]]
#[1] 851.5489 924.9473
#
#[[7]]
#[1] 860.3277 924.9473
#....
```